# Cannot build angular 8 application with nested lazy-loaded module in library

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I'm using angular to create an **ui library**.
In workspace, there is one project for **main app**, one project for **ui library**.

In the library which declares modules and routings, I have this code:

**parent-routing.module.ts**:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {ParentComponent} from './parent.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ParentComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: '/child/child.module#ChildModule'
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class ParentRoutingModule {
}
```

In **app.module.ts**, I declare the **ParentModule** as below:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('ui-lib').then(m => m.ParentModule)
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

When I tried compiling my app, the console throws me an error:

**ERROR in ./src/app/app-routing.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './../../../../dist/ui-lib/modules/parent/parent.module.d.ngfactory' in '/Users/linhnguyen/nested-module-playground/projects/main-app/src/app'**

After searching on Google, I found [this comment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6373#issuecomment-453006158). The commenter mentioned about creating a module and import every component to the route. That can resolve the issue of loading module in library, but it is not lazy loaded.

Here is [my workspace on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/alakanzam/ui-lib-playground)

Does anyone have any solutions please ?

Thanks,

---

**UPDATE**

In my `main application`, I declared the wrapper modules for parent & child component as below:

- child-wrapper.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ChildComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ]
})
export class ChildWrapperModule {

}
```

- parent-wrapper.module.ts:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ParentComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('./child-wrapper.module').then(m => m.ChildWrapperModule)
      }
    ]
  }
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ]
})
export class ParentWrapperModule {

}
```

- app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./lazy-module/parent-wrapper.module').then(m => m.ParentWrapperModule)
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

This archieve my goal, but in my opinion, it seems to be **STUPID**, because when developers want to use `ui-library`, they have to re-declare the routing in the application.

Any better ideas please ?

Comment: I agree it seems wrong to have to redeclare the routes in the application that implements the parent library.  Did you ever find a work around for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
loadChildren: '/child/child.module#ChildModule'
```

Needs to be in the new Angular 8 import syntax

```
loadChildren: () => import('/child/child.module').then(m => m.ChildModule)
```

Not sure if you can lazy load modules built with the old pre Angular 8 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue while implementing this functionality in my project. I implemented it in angular 6 though. I think the recommended solution given in the google comment is correct. In your main app you have to create a wrapper module for example `libwrapper` module which will only import the library module. And in app.module.ts in the routes declaration you can refer `libwrapper` module and this should fix your issue. Hipe this helps..

Comment: I have tried with wrapper module, but it seems not to work with nested module as above. Or am I doing wrong ?

Comment: From the posted scenario i will assume the childModule is part of the ui-lib library which as a whole is being lazy-loaded in the main app. Can you please prove the wrapper module that u have created in the main app?

Comment: The src has been updated in the question above. You can take a look :)